# React-data-grid sorting is not working for row selection checkbox column

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I select the first record and do sorting but the respective row selection checkbox is not changed its order.
refer example here, https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-column-sorting-forked-35p6d

Refer attached screenshot
[image]
[image]

Version - :

"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-data-grid": "5.0.1"